# Pass a query to informatica

Tags: sql, teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to pass a complete query to source qualifier of Informatica powercenter Designer. Since the query is large I cannot parameterize it (limitations of UNIX also comes here).

So, is there a way I can refer and run a query without hardcoding it inside Informatica, and get the result in Informatica.

Any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the query in a view and reference it in the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipeline function or table function and Use that in SQ Override. They have advantage over views where you can pass in parameters to the Function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL transformation , where you can pass/parse large queries via SQL tranformaton. Informatica Help has good guidance on this.